# laying hardwood floor in the basement over concrete and vinyl

Tags: hardwood-floor

I'm laying hardwood flooring in the basement, I was told that I can lay the wood over the vinyl but how do I level the vinyl is it true that I can use roof shingles?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to go with a primer and liquid leveling agent.  The problem with usinng shingles for something like this is getting the shingles to bind with the vinyl.  They would normally be stapled to a wood subfloor.